# Xcode compiler errors when using ##__VA_ARGS__

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macros, variadic

Here is my customized NSLog.

```
#define NSLog(fmt, ...) printf("%s,%d\n %s\n\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat:fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__].UTF8String)
```

This log is work good on another project, but it occurred 4 error when compiler time in current project. If using `__VA_ARGS__`, like `#define NSLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)`, it's going to compile successful. I think that maybe caused in `Building Setting`.

[image: error 1]

[image: error 2]

[image: error 3]

[image: error 4]

It's anyone has any idea to help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the header file declaring this imports Foundation. Check that you don't have NSLog defined somewhere else as well and finally, really not a good idea to redefine NSLog. You're probably better off adopting a logging framework or defining your own like this:

```
#define MELog(fmt, ...) NSLog("%s,%d\n %s\ ....
```

Comment: The header that overwrites `NSLog` would have to be always included after framework (system) headers otherwise it will pollute the compilation of the frameworks. Some frameworks are written in C and `[NSString stringWithFormat]` won't work there. That explains the error messages.